# Why does this code result in EXC_BAD_ACCESS when using ARC?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I am converting an old iPhone project to use ARC. I'm presenting a modal view controller and getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS when dismissing it - can't figure out why, and I suspect I'm missing something fundamental about how ARC works.

The view controller being presented is CorrectionsController, and it uses a delegate to let its presenting view controller know to dismiss it.  These are the relevant bits from the header file:

```
@protocol CorrectionsControllerDelegate
   - dismissCorrectionsController;
@end

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<CorrectionsControllerDelegate> correctionsDelegate;
```

The controller gets initialized in this method:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil delegate:(id<CorrectionsControllerDelegate>)_delegate {
    if (self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil]) {
        self.correctionsDelegate = _delegate;   
        // do other init stuff
    }
    return self;
}
```

The dismiss button calls this method:

```
- (void)cancelCorrection {
    if (self.correctionsDelegate)
        [self.correctionsDelegate dismissCorrectionsController];  
        // EXC_BAD_ACCESS happens here
}
```

The **presenting** view controller initializes the CorrectionsController like this:

```
// in .h file
@property (nonatomic, strong)    CorrectionsController *corrections;
@property (nonatomic, strong)   UINavigationController *secondNavigationController;

// in .m file
    NSString *nibName = @"CorrectionsController";
    self.corrections = [[CorrectionsController alloc] initWithNibName:nibName bundle:nil delegate:self];
    self.secondNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.corrections];
    if (isiPad()) {
        self.secondNavigationController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
    }
    [self presentViewController:self.secondNavigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

And it implements the CorrectionsControllerDelegate protocol:

```
- (void)dismissCorrectionsController {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:TRUE completion:nil];
}
```

Now, the fun part.  When stepping through the code, execution flows into cancelCorrection, enters dismissCorrectionsController in the delegate, returns to cancelCorrection, and EXC_BAD_ACCESS at the **end** of cancelCorrection.

[image]

[image]

self.correctionsDelegate appears to be pointing to a valid object at all times (inspecting it in the Variables view shows the object and values I would expect, and I get the following in the console which looks okay).

```
(lldb) po self.correctionsDelegate
<SyncController: 0x17b9a970>
```

The parts that really confuse me:

1) the stack trace shows the EXC_BAD_ACCESS is happening inside **objc_retain**.  **Why?**  What is being retained here?

2) what does the 0x44 memory address refer to?

Comment: Please do the following. Set a breakpoint inside the `cancelCorrection` method on the following line `if (self.correctionsDelegate)`. When your application hits the breakpoint type in the console `po self.correctionsDelegate` and let me know what the output is.

Comment: Updated the question.  As far as I can tell self.correctionsDelegate is pointing to a valid object, which is the presenting view controller.

Comment: Since this seems to be a memory corruption error (`objc_retain`), you might want to enable zombie objects. http://iosdevelopertips.com/debugging/updated-tracking-down-exc_bad_access-errors-with-nszombieenabled-in-xcode-4.html Also, let me point out that `if (someObject) [someObject someMethod];` is redundant, since `[nil someMethod];` is valid Objective-C

Comment: Zombies enabled, doesn't catch anything. I might be wrong, but the memory address that causes the crash (0x44) doesn't look like a valid address that was released... also, I can't figure out why it's trying to retain something in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best explanation I can find so far is that the modal controller (CorrectionsController) seems to be released right away in dismissCorrectionsController, and is no longer valid when execution returns to cancelCorrection.  This change seems to fix the crash:

```
- (void)cancelCorrection {
    [self.correctionsDelegate performSelector:@selector(dismissCorrectionsController) ];
}
```

I'll mark this answer as accepted but it still doesn't make complete sense to me, so if someone has a better explanation for what's happening I'll be happy to accept that answer instead.

Comment: Try disassembling around the location of the crash and/or single stepping the assembly code.

Comment: Interesting. Have you looked at the stack trace of this version? It's just imaginable that `performSelector:` does something like calling through to `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`, returning immediately and "queueing" the message on the run loop.

Answer (score -1):

I think this answer is very late to help question asker **alex_c** but It could help someone.

The code has a problem.

```
@protocol CorrectionsControllerDelegate
   - dismissCorrectionsController;
@end
```

missed return type.

```
@protocol CorrectionsControllerDelegate
   - (void)dismissCorrectionsController;
@end
```